# Does one who has no intention of sleeping say the blessing of Hashkivaynu after the evening Shema?

Tags: shema, sleep, bircas-krias-shema

Does one who has no intention of sleeping during the night say the blessing of Hashkivaynu after the evening Shema?

Comment: I would think he does, as saying it is part of the obligation of reading the Shema, and there is a separate blessing for going to sleep - _ha-Mapil_.

Comment: @Tamir hamapil is said on the fact that people go to sleep, just like urban dwellers say hanotein lasechvi vina without hearing a chicken and mourners say blessings on footwear. (There is a minority opinion that people who don't sleep can't say the blessings related to sleep (hamapil, hamaavir, yaef koach, elokai neshama) and some are strict therefore to hear them from someone else)

Comment: The prayer is written in the plural and refers to Klal Yisroel.

Comment: interesting side point in meseches brachos it's discussed that if someone were to recite shema at amud hashachar he would not recite Hashkivaynu b/c even though it's still time to be asleep it's no longer a time when it's normal for people to be going to sleep.